# Read integer from a line in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, input

## scala

I'm new to scala programming.i'm writing a code to read the integers from a line .what i did is :

1. read the line of interger(1 2 4 5 6)
2. read the character at 0,2,4,6 postion since space 1,3,5 are blank space,  but when it comes to read 10 only 1 is reed .

my code is

```
 val size: Int = Console.readInt // First line read the no of integers
    val reading: String = Console.readLine // String of integer(1 4 6 7 8)

    val readingSize: Int = reading.length

    var inp: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](size)
    for (a <- 0 until readingSize if (a % 2 == 0)) inp(a / 2) = reading(a) //converting into integer array(will be ASCII value)
      println("Output : " )
       for (b <- 0 until inp.length) 
         print(inp(b).toChar + " " )
```

So for example for input (1 3 5 6 7) it works but for (1 2 10 9) it will stop at 1 2 1.

i'ma beginner and so i don't whether this is completely bad logic for reading scala.
Hope my question is clear
Thanks in advance (and also input should in single with a single space between value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your integers from std in are delimited with spaces, why don't you just split them basing on known separator?

```
"1 2 10 9".split(' ')
// Array(1, 2, 10, 9)
```

Comment: ok . its works and one more doubt - while spliting whether the index of the array adjust ?? mean " 1 2 10 9" array(0)=1 ,array(2)=2...ryt..while spliting whether array(0)=1,array(1)=2,array(3)=10

Comment: @Warlock splitted tokens will be in the same order they are in the line, if you want to rearrange them in order by value you can convert every token to integer (rather than string) and then sort them: `"1 2 10 9".split(' ').map(x => x.toInt).sorted`

Comment: What i mean is the INDEX OF ARRAY??..while splitting ' '(black space) occupies a place in array ..ryt?? like arr[0]=1 ,arr[1]=' ',arr[2]=2,arr[3]=' '..hope you got what i meant ?

Comment: @Warlock not quite sure. If you're complaining that with multiple spaces you can have empty strings in resulting array you can split with `split(" +")` - this means *at least one space between tokens*

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? `"1 4 10 40 53 54".split(" ").map(_.toInt)` yields `Array(1, 4, 10, 40, 53, 54)` (array of type Int). What you wanted to have?

Comment: exactly that it givin 1 4 1 space space space ....
3 //size
12 34 56 //input
Output : 
1 4 //output

Comment: got it a small mistake from me ...sorry for the trouble!!
But array index not in proper order ! ...

Answer (score 0):

I know what is your problem.
if for statement you have "if (a % 2 == 0)" where a is the index of string 'reading'. This code will work only for digits, because if I have string (3 5 4 8 7) in this string index of spaces is odd, and if I take only even indexed numbers I will get the resulting numbers. But if I had string (23 4 17 4 2) here is 3 is standing on odd index, and because of constraint"(a % 2 == 0)" I will simply lose it. 
In your case for (1 3 5 6 7)  it will work just fine, because you have only digits there, but for (1 2 10 9), it will print 1, then miss 0, and print space and that's it. It will actually print 1,2,1 and space, but you cant see space, that's why you thought it stopped at 1.

But there is a simpler way of doing this, you can take some string st, which is numbers and spaces, and take st.split(" ").toList which will give you a list of desired ints only in string typed, and for this list you can use map function like this: list map (p => Integer.parseInt(p)) what it does is it will take each element p from the list and replace it with the resulting element which we get by Integer.parseInt(p) function.